# Finding pk from several tables

Tags: sql

Does anyone know how to find a pk for a table created from a retrieval query from several tables
Or how can such a pk be set?
Thank you!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav,SSMS

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
       o.name AS TableName
     , i.name AS IndexName
     , c.name AS ColumnName
     , i.type_desc
     , i.is_primary_key
     , TYPE_NAME(c.system_type_id) as Datatype
 FROM sys.objects o
 INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.object_id = o.object_id
 INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id=i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
 INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id=ic.object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
 WHERE i.is_primary_key=1
 ORDER BY
     o.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you looking in MySql

```
select * 
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    where COLUMN_KEY = "PRI" AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DBName';
```